# Entity Framework error "Could not find stored procedure ''"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6.4

Our C# application, using Entity Framework 6.4.4 to access an SQL Server instance, intermittently fails to return data from a stored procedure and throws n exception

> EntityCommandExecutionException: Could not find stored procedure ' '

This has happened on a customer's production server about a dozen times over the past several months. We tried to troubleshoot this problem by examining SQL Server logs and exception details that we capture into Windows event logs. We attempted on multiple occasions to reproduce the problem under controlled conditions on development and staging servers, but could not successfully duplicate it.

Scouring the Web for information, we have never found any documentation about this particular problem. The closest we ever found was a [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/666) in the Entity Framework 6 project on GitHub when implementing `IDbInterceptor`. We implemented an interceptor on a single query; however, we encountered this error on other queries that didn't use the interceptor.

The kind of error behaves suspiciously like a resource exhaustion problem. However, this is not supported by examination of application and server logs that do not show any unusually high resource usage when these errors occur.

The code that calls the stored procedure is generated from an EDMX file (database-first model) by the Entity Model Code Generator in Visual Studio. Examples of the stored procedure method, call, and data type are as follows; all our stored procedure calls follow the same pattern. A stack trace from the captured exception points directly to one of these calls. None of the stored procedure methods ever omit the name and they work under normal circumstances.

Example entity type `GetAllConditionCodes_Result`:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DAL.Entities
{
    using System;
    
    public partial class GetAllConditionCodes_Result
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ConditionCodeNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EF method that calls a stored procedure `GetAllConditionCodes`, named by a string literal in the `ExecuteFunction` call:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<GetAllConditionCodes_Result> GetAllConditionCodes(Nullable<System.DateTime> lastUpdateTime)
{
    var lastUpdateTimeParameter = lastUpdateTime.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("LastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime) :
            new ObjectParameter("LastUpdateTime", typeof(System.DateTime));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetAllConditionCodes_Result>("GetAllConditionCodes", lastUpdateTimeParameter);
}
```

Application method, in our data access layer, that requests the stored procedure call. The `Mapper.Map` statement just shows our use of AutoMapper to convert entities (`GetAlLConditionCodes_Result`) into data model (`ConditionCode`) objects. The `CreateObjectContext` call returns the EF `DbContext` object that provides entity access to the database.

```
public List<ConditionCode> GetAllConditionCodesFromDatabase(DateTime? lastUpdateTime = null)
{
    var conditionCodes = new List<ConditionCode>();

    using (var context = CreateObjectContext())
    {
        var result = context.GetAllConditionCodes(lastUpdateTime).ToList();
        conditionCodes = Mapper.Map<List<Entities.GetAllConditionCodes_Result>, List<ConditionCode>>(result);
    }

    return conditionCodes;
}
```

The outer exception

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

that our application captures contains the message:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

The inner exception (type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`) contains the (literal) message:

> Could not find stored procedure ' '

Note that the reported name is a string containing a single space character instead of the name of the stored procedure that should have been called.

Any help in leading to a resolution of this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Database first method has been obsoleted but still should work with Framework 6.6.4.  if you are not finding a stored procedure it is probably due to a credential issue.  When you check the log files what is the User/Group when it works and does not work?  I'm suspecting the Domain Server may not be timing out when getting the credentials.  Then when the Server looks for the Stored Procedure not finding due to the failed credentials.  This is only a guess, but I've seen lots of credentials failures in a Window Domain.

Comment: Quite possibly this is a bug in EF 6 that will never be fixed. Why are you so far behind the curve?

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by "database first method has been obsoleted"? I am not having any luck finding anything about that.

Comment: @SeanLange see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/january/data-points-looking-ahead-to-entity-framework-7#dropping-edmx-but-database-first-will-continue

Comment: @jdweng. Thanks. I saw that one yesterday when I saw your comment but thought maybe it was not just limited to EDMX based on your comment.

Comment: @IanKemp It works. You say "behind the curve", I say "using stable, well-known technology". It's a very large project with many developers and several large customer installations.

Comment: But it's not stable. It has bugs, as you've possibly just discovered, and those bugs are never going to be fixed. Your mindset is why we still have COBOL mainframes.

Comment: @IanKemp Your comment doesn't help solve the problem. All non-trivial software has bugs that are never going to be fixed. Your mindset is why we still have Windows.